# WPF scrambled window over window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

A strange phenomenon when a new window is opened over the existing main window.

99% of the time the window is opened as should, but sometimes it opened as shown in the attached picture.
It's happened to me in two separate applications which have the same basic window interface.
I use the ShowDialog() to open the new window and I don't know if it is relevant or not, but I'm using a helper static class to open the window and to store the window (custom) DialogResult.

The application is running on an SBC device with an LCD (640X480) attached.
The problem occurred on several devices.
For now, I could not reproduce this on the development machine (Windows 10 and VS2017).

[image]

Comment: Can you verify that you are using the latest graphics driver on your device? A while ago I have seen similar artifacts on some of our development machines, not just in our own WPF application but also in other, 3rd party WPF applications. A driver update seems to have fixed the problem for us.

Comment: Well, after few days of investigations I also came across a similar post which also suggest to update the graphic driver.
So yesterday I checked this out and indeed our systems didn't use the latest graphic driver so I've update them and currently since the update I didn't saw this happening again, but as it 99% of the time working properly I don't want to jump to the conclusion that this is the fix, Just need more time and testing.
but It's look promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a graphic card driver problem, more then 6 months now and the problem didn't occured again since the graphic card driver update.